# Pandas Dataframe: For loop that adds a fixed integer if the value exists in previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, for-loop

for the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rounds':[1000,1000,1000,1000,3000,3000,4000,5000,6000,6000]})
```

I would like to have a for loop that if the value already exists in previous rows, a fixed int, in this case 25, is added to the value and creates:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Rounds':[1000,1025,1050,1075,3000,3025,4000,5000,6000,6025]})
```

Initially I tried

```
for i in df.index:
    if df.iat[i,1] == df.iloc[i-1,1]:
        df.iat[i,1] = df.iat[i-1,1]+25
```

The problem is that it doesn't work for more than two similar values in a column and I would like to give column name "Rounds" instead of the index of column.

Answer (score 3):

You need [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df['Rounds'] += df.groupby('Rounds').cumcount()*25
```

output:

```
   Rounds
0    1000
1    1025
2    1050
3    1075
4    3000
5    3025
6    4000
7    5000
8    6000
9    6025
```

intermediate:

```
df.groupby('Rounds').cumcount()

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    0
5    1
6    0
7    0
8    0
9    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: `cumcount` clever solution!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html?highlight=cumcount#pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount):

```
df["Rounds"] += df.groupby(df["Rounds"]).cumcount() * 25
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
   Rounds
0    1000
1    1025
2    1050
3    1075
4    3000
5    3025
6    4000
7    5000
8    6000
9    6025
```

Comment: great minds thinks alike ;) +1

Comment: @mozway Indeed!